# iwconfig essid keeps resetting/clearing

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

When I try to set an ESSID to my network card it keeps resetting/clearing almost right away back to off/any. If I put:

```
iwconfig <dev> essid <ssid>
iwconfig
```

in a script it always works. But if I place a sleep of 0.2 or more in between the iwconfig commands the essid is reset back to off/any.

I checked and NetworkManager is disabled. Power Management is off.  AP is open (no encryption).

What would cause that?

I notice some stuff with "ip monitor" when trying to set the essid:

```
3: wlp11s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
    link/ether 
3: wlp11s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DORMANT group default 
    link/ether 00:21:5c:53:04:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp11s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
    link/ether 
3: wlp11s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
    link/ether 
3: wlp11s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
    link/ether 
3: wlp11s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 00:21:5c:53:04:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

But not sure what that means?

I also noticed if I set an essid that doesn't exist in the scan it sticks then.

Comment: if I set an essid that doesn't exist then it sticks, why?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I got it to stick.  I killed dbus-daemon and now it sticks.  So some other process (not sure which yet) is listening to dbus messages and interfering.

After using dbus-monitor I found it was wpa_supplicant which is running with -u flag (dbus monitoring).